# Central limit theorem and statistical uncertainities

Tags: distributions, sampling, uncertainty

I am unable to understand the statement that the statistical uncertainties associated with measured data are have to be gaussian distributed because of the CLT theorem. What I know about CLT is that if we generate a sampling distribution of sample size n, and plot the mean or the average value of all the samples, then this distribution approaches gaussian distribution as sample size increases. But from this, how could we comment on the uncertainties associated with our measured values?

Comment: Could you try being more precise where are you lost?

Comment: @Tim The confusion I have is that CLT talks about gaussian distribution of mean values while the statement I wrote talks about the uncertanity associated with each individual measurement which is said to be gaussian in nature. In other words, if CLT talks about the distribution of mean values, the statement I wrote talks about the distribution of one individual measurement...